# While Controller with a Counter for multiple users in a Threadgroup - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to add a While Controller to check if a value in my **GET** call returns **'COMPLETED'**. I also want to add a **Counter** to prevent it in going infinite loop. I added a while controller with below javascript code:

**${__javaScript("${STATUS}" !="COMPLETED" || "${COUNTERA}" < 5,)}**

I am retrieving STATUS paramter from previous GET call using JSON extractor. COUNTERA is set to start with 0 and Increment by 1. Above code does not work and while controller does not stop the execution event though STATUS is COMPLETED.

Any help would be appreacited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to stop when condition becomes "false"

> The While Controller runs its children until the condition is "false".

Prefer __jexl3, __groovy function over __javaScript

> use of __jexl3, __groovy function, properties or variables as needed.

And just remove unneeded comma and brackets:

```
 ${__jexl3("${STATUS}" !="COMPLETED" && ${COUNTERA} < 5)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using jexl3 funciton now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Amend your While Controller condition to too like

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${STATUS}" !="COMPLETED" && ${COUNTERA} < 5,)}
   ```

   You need to remove quotation marks around `${COUNTERA}` as JavaScript treats it like a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) therefore your comparison fails.
2. You might also want to declare COUNTERA variable with the value of `0` in [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to avoid JavaScript error during first iteration when the variable is not initialized yet

   [image: JMeter User Defined Variables]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding a USer Defined Variable fixed the complilation error.